# Does Xalan with Java 6 skip comments?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xalan

It appears to me that the version of Xalan that ships with JDK 6 (and 7) does not process comments in the input file, as specified by `<xsl:template match="comment()" ...>...`

Given the following input file, dangling.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<dangling xmlns:dt="urn:uuid:e2973380-8daf-11e3-a5d8-0002a5d5c51b">
   <!--  This is a comment. -->
   <foobar x="y">A bar where I drink foo beer,
           after debugging XSLT in hell all day.</foobar>
</dangling>
```

and the stylesheet identity_sans_dt.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:dt="urn:uuid:e2973380-8daf-11e3-a5d8-0002a5d5c51b">


<xsl:output method="xml"
            encoding="UTF-8"
            indent="yes" 
            omit-xml-declaration="yes"
            />

   <xsl:template match="/ | attribute::* | comment()">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the following output using libxml's xsltproc

```
<dangling>
   <!--  This is a comment. -->
   <foobar x="y">A bar where I drink foo beer,
           after debugging XSLT in hell all day.</foobar>
</dangling>
```

However, when I run the same thing through a Java program that applies the same stylesheet using a SAX TransformerHandler, I get this.

```
<dangling>

   <foobar x="y">A bar where I drink foo beer,
           after debugging XSLT in hell all day.</foobar>
</dangling>
```

Am I doing something wrong that is causing what technical specifications euphemistically call "unpredictable results?"  Or does there appear to be a Xalan bug responsible for the omission of the comment in the Java version?

While not directly related to the question on comment() handling, here is the background for this exercise.  dangling.xml is the result of some previous processing that had stripped out all of the elements in the dt namespace and their children.  For some reason, the dt namespace declaration was left behind.  In addition, the xml declaration was causing some problems. (This was because some downstream code was manipulating this as a string, and just plopping it into the middle of another string of XML text. Don't bother telling me how horrible this is; I know.  Don't bother telling those responsible for said code; I have already.)  So I spent an inordinate amount of time trying to get rid of these two annoying artifacts, but keep everything else.

No, dangling.xml isn't the REAL file, just a proxy for debugging.  :-)

So if there is a completely better approach that sidesteps the whole problem, I'd be interested in knowing about that, too.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that you are running it incorrectly. In SAX, the XMLReader notifies most parsing events to the registered ContentHandler, but not comments, which are sent to the registered LexicalHandler. The JAXP TransformerHandler implements both the ContentHandler and LexicalHandler interfaces, but it will only be notified of comments if it is registered with the XMLReader both as the ContentHandler and as the LexicalHandler.

Comment: Thank you Michael. There is no setLexicalHandler method on the XMLReader; see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/XMLReader.html. The code in question actually uses TransformerHandler, which it sets as the ContentHandler on the TransformerHandler. So how would one specify that this is to be the LexicalHandler, too?

Comment: Update: In response to Michael's suggestion, I searched the JavaDocs for setLexicalHandler. There is such a method on the SAXResult, but it states that "If the lexical handler is not set, an attempt should be made by the transformer to cast the ContentHandler to a LexicalHandler." So the TransformerHandler is doing both already. However, the StreamResult (set on the TransformerHandler for its output) has no such option. Does this imply that one can't stream out comment nodes with SAX? That sounds unlikely to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide the answer for anyone else who stumbles across this annoying problem.

But first, though, I'll again thank Michael Kay for pointing me in the direction of the eventual solution.

The problem was that the lexical handler needed to be set on the original XMLReader which was processing the input in the first place.  I had mistakenly construed the problem to be that there had to be a lexical handler to pick up comments for the purpose of writing the final result.  So I'd misunderstood the advice given.

After doing more research, I discovered the answer to my follow up question, which was "How does one set the lexical analyzer on the XMLReader?"  This is, in my view, very well hidden.  Instead of a straightforward setLexicalHandler method, as there is on a SAXResult, there is instead a setProperty method on both the SAXParser and the XMLReader objects.

```
 void XMLReader.setProperty(String name, Object value);
 void SAXParser.setProperty(String name, Object value);
```

The "standard" property names are URLs specified at http://sax.sourceforge.net/apidoc/org/xml/sax/package-summary.html#package_description.  Other implementations may add their own peculiar properties, as long as they use a URL that doesn't conflict with the standard.  This seems like a good sort of extension mechanism, but I can't understand why they used it for an object that is a standard part of the API; or, conversely, why they didn't specify everything (including the ContentHander) the same way.  (In other words, do it consistently.)

So, in lieu of what, in my not-at-all humble opinion should have been a simple setLexicalHandler method, one must instead use the string `""http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler"` to indicate that one is setting the lexical handler, and provide the handler as the second (non-type-safe Object) argument.

So here is the relevant portion of the "front end" of my program:

```
        saxReader = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
        saxReader.setContentHandler(transformsHandler);
        saxReader.setProperty("http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", transforms[0]);
```

If you fail to include the setProperty call, your transformer will never even see the comments in the input, so, as in my case, it won't matter whether your XSLT handles them.  And that was Michael's original, condensed explanation.

Comment: Thanks for adding the gory detail, which I recall struggling with myself years ago when I last did anything in this area.

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked, the versions of Apache Xalan and Xerces which shipped with the Sun/Oracle JREs were many years out of date and had many known bugs and limitations. Unless Oracle has corrected this in Java 7 or Java 8 -- and even if they have -- I would STRONGLY recommend that you download current copies direct from Apache and use those instead.

(The IBM JRE -- which, alas, is not available except as part of an IBM product -- tracked Apache more closely, partly because the IBM team was the original donors of Xalan and Xerces and stayed involved in supporting them. Recent IBM JREs replaced Xalan with IBM's next-generation XSLT processor, XL-TXE. IBM WebSphere shipped an advanced version of XL-TXE as part of its XML Feature Pack; that version added support for XQuery 1.0, XSLT 2.0, and XPath 2.0.)

Comment: There is also Saxon, which at least implements XSLT 2.0. Apache Xalan itself has been stuck at 1.0 forever, and hasn't been even re-released since 2007.

Comment: True. The problem with the IBM team having contributed so much to Xalan was that when they had to shift their attention away from it there weren't a lot of other folks ready to pick up the slack.